# How to automatically login Okta user with active login session to .NET 4.5 Web Forms app

Tags: authentication, webforms, .net-4.5, okta

I've got a .NET 4.5 Web Forms app with Okta authentication on top. The authentication setup seems to be working fine; I can login and logout and get my Okta user info/claims from the context variable.

What I'd like to do is detect on page load whether a user already has an active Okta session in their browser and then log them into the application. Or if they don't have a session do nothing and stay on the application page.

Making a challenge call to the authentication manager

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Login.aspx" },
    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

almost does what I want. If the user has an active session it'll do some redirects and log them in. But if they're not logged in they get sent to, and left on, the Okta login page. Which is not what I want.

I thought I would be able to access some cookies that Okta sets when a user logs in via an Okta page, but when checking through the browser debugger and checking `Request.Cookies` they don't seem to be available at that stage. And the context doesn't have access to the user info either.

edit: Also, if it helps, this is what my Startup.cs looks like

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using IdentityModel.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication.Startup))]

namespace WebApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {

        // These values are stored in Web.config. Make sure you update them!
        private readonly string _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"];

        private readonly string _redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"];
        private readonly string _authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OrgUri"];
        private readonly string _clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"];

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = _clientId,
                ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
                Authority = _authority,
                RedirectUri = _redirectUri,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                Scope = "openid profile email offline_access",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                    {
                        // Exchange code for access and ID tokens
                        var tokenClient = new TokenClient($"{_authority}/v1/token", _clientId, _clientSecret);

                        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, _redirectUri);
                        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                        }

                        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient($"{_authority}/v1/userinfo");
                        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                        var claims = new List<Claim>(userInfoResponse.Claims)
                        {
                            new Claim("code", n.Code),
                            new Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken),
                            new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken),
                            new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken)
                        };

                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
                    },
                },
            });
        }
    }
}
```